# Laravel many-to-many relationship with additional pivot data

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I am having a `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_name_unique` (`name`)
) ;
```

and then `user_roles` table which is defined like this:

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('user_roles')) {
            Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('role');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
            });
        }
```

and stores values such as `actor`, `director` etc

And a `user_record` pivot table:

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('user_record')) {
            Schema::create('user_record', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('record_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('user_role_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('character_name');
                $table->integer('ranking');
            });
        }
```

So, one `Record` has many `User` which has many `User_Role` for this `Record`.

All Ids in `user_record` are the foreign key to the respective fields.

Is this called a hasManyThrough relationship and if so how does the `user_roles()` in `User` model look like?

```
public function user_roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserRole::class, 'record_user', 'user_id', 'record_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have got a typical simple **[`Many To Many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)** relationship here, with two tables and the third pivot that contains the `id`'s of the both.

And the relation should contain both `id`'s instead like :

```
public function user_roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserRole::class, 'user_record', 'user_id', 'user_role_id');
    ______________________________________________^^^^^^^^^^^_______________^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for shedding some light here, @Zakaria Archarki.